# Somebody please explain this line broadly. Tenses and Meaning

Tags: tense

We deliberately stripped out everything that might get in the way of leaning whatever it is we're working on at that point in the book.

Answer (score 0):

"Stripped out" *literally* means to remove all fixtures and fittings (eg furniture, decoration) from a room or building.

*Metaphorically*, it can mean to remove all unnecessary details from something so that it is clearer.

Your example:

> We deliberately stripped out everything that might get in the way of learning whatever it is we're working on at that point in the book.

It means they removed or avoided focusing on unnecessary details so that they could concentrate on learning the *main points* in their studies.